# php array_map is not mapping arrays correctly

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am fetching data from db.I am looping over the sql query and array_map() to get proper value.

```
$CompleteData = array();

foreach ( $Details as $d ) {
    $q = "SELECT "
        . "`log`.`id` AS 'id', "
        . "DATE_FORMAT( `log`.`timestamp`, '%d %b %Y %h:%i:%s %p' ) AS 'timestamp', "
        . "`log`.`Author` AS 'Author', "
        . "`log`.`message` AS 'message', "
        . "`log`.`bookname` AS 'bookname' "
        . "FROM `log` "
        . "WHERE `log`.`detailId` = '" . $d  . "'  "
        . "ORDER BY `log`.`timestamp` DESC, `log`.`id` DESC";

    $qr = mysql_query($q, $sql);
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($qr); ++$i) {
        $LogId[$i] = mysql_result($qr, $i, 'id');
        $LogTimestamp[$i] = mysql_result($qr, $i, 'timestamp');
        $LogAuthor[$i] = mysql_result($qr, $i, 'Author');
        $LogMessage[$i] = mysql_result($qr, $i, 'shortmessage');
        $Logbookname[$i] = mysql_result($qr, $i, 'bookname');
    }

    $CompleteData[$d] = array_map(null, $LogId, $LogTimestamp, $LogAuthor, $LogMessage, $Logbookname);
}
```

Here array_map is not mapping data as desired and the output is collapsed.

Log table in DB:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

But with `array_map(null,array1,arrar3..)` the output is like below

[image]

It is combining 1st array with 2nd array and so on.

Can you pls tell am I doing wrong with array map?

Comment: Why are you using array_map since you are not modifying the array? Will an associative array work for your purpose? It'll return an array with column names instead of index.

Comment: You don't need `array_map` and `for`, see @MateiMihai 's answer. But the problem in your code is that you are not emptying your arrays, like `$LogId` and `$LogTimestamp` so they will contain items from first iteration too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing it really wrong.

First I would like to inform you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated and it's better starting looking for `PDO`, `mysqli_` functions or `MySQLi` class and, of course, prepared statements.

What you are trying to do can be simplified as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT "
    . "`log`.`id` AS 'id', "
    . "DATE_FORMAT( `log`.`timestamp`, '%d %b %Y %h:%i:%s %p' ) AS 'timestamp', "
    . "`log`.`Author` AS 'Author', "
    . "`log`.`message` AS 'message', "
    . "`log`.`bookname` AS 'bookname' "
    . "FROM `log` "
    . "WHERE `log`.`detailId` IN ('" . implode("', '", $Details) . "') "
    . "ORDER BY `log`.`timestamp` DESC, `log`.`id` DESC";

$stmt = mysql_query($query);

$CompleteData = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($stmt)) {
    if (!isset($CompleteData[$row['detailedId']])) {
        $CompleteData[$row['detailedId']] = array($row);
    } else {
        $CompleteData[$row['detailedId']][] = $row;
    }
}
```

Why is better this way?

1. You are executing a single query to get the info for all the logs
2. The complexity of the code is smaller so the execution will be faster
3. The code is more readable and easy to understand

**Later edit:**

If your `$Details` variable is an array of objects you can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to get only the info you need to use in the query:

```
$detailsIds = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item->detailsId;
}, $Details);
```

having the details ids you can use the array to create the where statement:

```
"WHERE `log`.`detailId` IN ('" . implode("', '", $detailsIds) . "')
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that shouldn't the key be `detailId`? You beat me to it!

Comment: I saw the mistake after a short review :)

Comment: @MateiMihai,,,thanks for such a good answer..What if `$Details` is not only having detailsId..if it is an array object with some data.From that we need to get only detailsId like `$Details->detailsId`..Is there any way to imlode that too?

Comment: It is an array of objects?

Comment: yes it is..Not in my code..Just want to know whether how to implode only one elements from array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think an associative array will format your response with the columns without the need to use array map.

[Associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)